# Dealing with size of stl containers

Tags: c++, stl

I'm rewriting a general purpose library that was written by me before I've learned STL. It uses C-style arrays all the way. In many places there is a code like this:

```
unsigned short maxbuffersize; // Maximum possible size of the buffer. Can be set by user.
unsigned short buffersize; // Current size of the buffer.
T *buffer; // The buffer itself.
```

The first thing I did was to change the code like this:

```
unsigned short maxbuffersize;
unsigned short buffersize;
std::vector<T> buffer;
```

And then:

```
typedef unsigned short BufferSize;
BufferSize maxbuffersize;
BufferSize buffersize;
std::vector<T> buffer;
```

And then I felt like I was doing a very bad thing and should reconsider my coding style. At first, BufferSize seemed like a very bad name for a type but then all kinds of weird questions started popping up. How do I name the size type? Should I use my own type or inherit from `std::vector<T>::size_type`? Should I cache the size of container or use `size()` all the way? Should I allow the user to manually set the maximum size of container and if not, how do I check for overflow?

I know that there can't be one-size-fits-all approach therefore I'd like to hear the policies other coders and framework vendors use. The library I'm working on is cross-platform general purpose and is intended to be released into public domain and be used for decades. Thanks.

Comment: Since your going to release it into the public domain, i think you should give your program a little plug.

Comment: It's the clone of [Source engine console](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console) with some limitations (such as only one instance) removed.

Comment: Ace, if you set up a repository on the internet (such as github) - post a link

Comment: There is an old version [here](http://code.google.com/p/four-mp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FShared%2FConsole). I've rewritten major parts since then and plan to release it when it'll be polished enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the default choice ought to be to get rid of both `buffersize` and `maxbuffersize` and use `buffer.size()` and `buffer.capacity()` throughout.

I would advise against caching the sizes *unless you have very specific reasons to do this, backed with hard data from profiler runs*. Caching would introduce extra complexity and the potential for the cache to get of sync with the real thing.

Finally, in places where you feel bounds checking is warranted, you could use `buffer.at(i)`. This will throw an exception if `i` is out of bounds.

Comment: Buffering the size of a `std::vector` is outright stupid, as it is guaranteed to have constant performance (ie independent of number of elements). This is also true for any other sequence container as far as I know (these including `std::array`, `std::string`, `std::valarray`)

Comment: @rubenvb really?  does `for(size_t i=0; i<buffer.size();++i)` not have to check the size of the buffer for every iteration - something that you the programmer might know does not change in the loop. (I agree with Aix - a profiler should be used to determine whether such checks are expensive - as they probably are not.).

Comment: What about naming convention? I think BufferSizeType is a good one, but there are instances where the fact that index is passed is opaque to the user and I don't know a good way to cover that.

Comment: @FaTony: My personal preference would be to use plain integer types in the user API, rather than having a separate `typedef` for every eventuality. Others might disagree.

Comment: Tom: it's a function call, yes, but the member function itself has constant time complexity, ie, it does not iterate over and count all elements. The size is updated as elements are added or removed (for *sequance containers* only of course, a `std::list` is completely different in this reagard, but not what the OP is asking about...)

Answer (score 2):

In general I would advise using iterators to access your data.  When you do this you often don't explicitly call the size of the container at all. This also decouples you from using `std::vector` all together - and lets you simply change to, for example `std::list` if you realize later that this better suits your needs.

When you use iterators the need for `vector.size()` in general greatly decreases.
(when you do need it use `buffer.size()` and `buffer.capacity()` as aix says).

For example:

```
typedef unsigned short BufferSize;
BufferSize maxbuffersize;
BufferSize buffersize;
std::vector<T> buffer;
for(unsigned short i = 0; i< maxbuffersize;++i)
{
  //do something with buffer[i];
}
```

becomes

```
struct do_something
{
  void operator()(const T& t) 
  { 
   //do something with buffer[i]
  }
};
std::vector<T> buffer(maxbuffersize);
std::for_each(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), do_something());
```

which is a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the size is useful for may structures, but it's a bit redundant for arrays/vectors, since the size is guaranteed to be the final index+1.  If you are worried about running past the end, an iterator approach such as was mentioned would solve this, as well as most other issues regarding possible sizes for comparisons, etc;

it's pretty standard to define all of your types and their sizes in a header with the API which sets them for different platforms and compilers...look at windows with it's definitions of LONG, ULONG, DWORD, etc.  The old "C" convention is to preface them with a unique name or initials such as MYAPI_SIZETYPE.  It's wordy but avoids any crossplatform confusion or compiler issues.

Comment: I put all my types into my own namespace and never use `using` to avoid name clashes.